# Language translator Delphi

Tags: delphi, translation, delphi-7

I am busy with a project where I have to code a program in Delphi that will translate an English word to another language. What would be the easiest way to approach this? I was thinking about using [Microsoft Translator V2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512423.aspx) API from Delphi, but it seems very complicated and I am not yet that experienced in Delphi. Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Here's](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/using-the-microsoft-translator-v2-from-delphi/) RRUZ's nice article about Microsoft Translator V2. So it would be good if you wait for him to post here something about it.

Comment: Thanks daemon_x I am looking into that right now it looks very complicated though.If I can maybe find a big enough database with words in it I can use SQL to Translate the words but I can't seem to find a database with more than one language in it.

Comment: @Rizla - I don't think local database is a good solution. I can't imagine how huge would be your application installation pack with several lexicons (depends on what you need). I guess you may find some free databases but I'm voting for the online translators.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [RRUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz) you can follow [this article](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/using-the-microsoft-translator-v2-from-delphi/) about [Microsoft Translator V2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512423.aspx)  API implementation for Delphi; inluding the full (even speaking) example.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to be self-contained, you could make a webservice call (soap, etc..) to the cloud (google, etc..).  The nature of your app (is it a translation program? or do you just want to provide translation in another app, along with spellcheck, thesaurus, syntax highlight, etc..?) will determine whether this is feasible or not.

Comment: The easiest way with the complete source code for Microsoft Translator V2 API is to read the [RRUZ's article](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/using-the-microsoft-translator-v2-from-delphi/). Nothing more to say. Anyway [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/language/translate/overview.html) is now deprecated and will be down on December 1, 2011.

Comment: Hey daemon_X thanks for the help man I figured it out now Seems like Ms translator is the way to go thanks alot :)!

Comment: @Rizla - so you finally decided to follow the online version; it's IMHO better than include tons of bytes with the installation package. Now it would be great if RRUZ post here a link to his own article and get the votes and acceptance for it, because it's again a good reading.

Comment: @daemon_x, I just saw this question. feel free to post the link to the article as an answer :) .